# Tkinter - Mark only one Checkbox

Tags: python, tkinter

The following code allows the user to select only one radiobutton. For example, if the user selects Type II button and then clicks the Type III button, the previous selection disappears.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

radiobutton_variable = IntVar()
Radiobutton(root, text="Type II",  variable = radiobutton_variable, value = 1).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Radiobutton(root, text="Type III", variable = radiobutton_variable, value = 2).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
Radiobutton(root, text="Type IV",  variable = radiobutton_variable, value = 3).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
Radiobutton(root, text="Type V",   variable = radiobutton_variable, value = 4).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

mainloop()
```

If I use the same code for the check button widget, I get the error message:

```
TclError: unknown option "-value"
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Radiobuttons and Checkboxes work differently. In Radiobutton, a set of buttons is mutually linked to one variable and the value decides which one should be displayed as active. In Checkboxes, each checkbox has an own variable and a value for checked and one for unchecked. They do not have the same arguments and work differently.

Comment: `Checkbutton` uses `onvalue` and `offvalue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two widgets have different purposes and should be used accordingly.

- `Radiobutton` allows selecting exactly *one* choice from a list of mutually exclusive ones.
- `Checkbutton` allows selecting *any number* of choices from the list.

Using `Radiobutton`s like you already do is most appropriate here.

While meaningless, forcing `Checkbutton`s to behave like `Radiobutton`s is technically possible.
Link the `Checkbutton`s to the same variable but set a unique `onvalue` for each.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

variable = tk.IntVar(root)

for onvalue in range(1, 5 + 1):
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(
        root,
        onvalue=onvalue,
        variable=variable,
    )
    checkbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkbuttons and radiobuttons have different options because they do different things.

A `Checkbutton` instance dosn't support a `value` option. Instead, it has an `onvalue` and `offvalue` option which specifies the value of the widget when it is on or off. `Checkbutton` widgets need to have their own unique `variable` as well.

If you want to limit the user so they can only pick one value out of many, a `Checkbutton` is the wrong widget to use. That is exactly what the `Radiobutton` is for. Radio buttons are for an exclusive choice, check buttons are for multiple choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use checkbutton if you want user to select only one checkbox. By running this code and select the option, you will get the idea.
I know others already answered your question. But maybe my answer can help someone.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
#Same variable but different values
radiobutton_variable = IntVar()
Radiobutton(root, text="Radiobutton only one", variable = radiobutton_variable, value = 1).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Radiobutton(root, text="Radiobutton only one",  variable = radiobutton_variable, value = 2).grid(row = 0, column = 1)

#Same variable but different values
checkbutton_variable = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Checkbutton only one",   variable = checkbutton_variable, onvalue = 3).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
Checkbutton(root, text="Checkbutton only one",  variable = checkbutton_variable, onvalue = 4).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

#Same variable, same values or no value
#Select both radio button
both_select_radiobutton_variable = IntVar()
Radiobutton(root, text="radiobutton both", variable = both_select_radiobutton_variable).grid(row = 2, column = 0)
Radiobutton(root, text="radiobutton both",  variable = both_select_radiobutton_variable).grid(row = 2, column = 1)

#Same variable, same values or no value
#Select both check button
both_select_checkbutton_variable = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Checkbutton both", variable = both_select_checkbutton_variable).grid(row = 3, column = 0)
Checkbutton(root, text="Checkbutton both",  variable = both_select_checkbutton_variable).grid(row = 3, column = 1)

mainloop()
```